# How to access child router in Aurelia?

Tags: router, aurelia

I have two child routers. I can navigate from one to other. But from the child router view, how can I navigate?

Below line of code gives the parent router instance.

`import {Router} from 'aurelia-router'`

How to get child router instance?

Comment: Where do you want to navigate and why can't you use injected router for this?

Comment: I have to navigate inside the child router. I'm not sure how to access the injected router from view model.

Comment: Inside of child view model you normally do `import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';` then inject into class and use it like `this.router.navigate('child2')`. Nothing really different here compared to normal rouiting.

Comment: I did same. But it gives instance reference of parent router not the child router. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Yes, it gives the same router instance, but you can still navigate between any routes you want, child-child, child-parent. Can you post some of your code, how are you trying to redirect?

Answer (score 4):

To create a child router, create a new router on a child route in the same way you created a router on the parent route. Then, set the router as a property of the view model class so you can access it throughout your view model.

```
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router';

class ChildViewModel() {  
    configureRouter(config, router) {
        this.router = router;
        // router config
    }
    someOtherFunction() {
        this.router.navigate('somewhere');
    }
}
```

If you then want to use the child router in another view model, you can import it and use the router on the class (assuming that the class is a singleton, which it should be unless you configure it otherwise).

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { ChildViewModel } from './child-view-model';

@inject(ChildViewModel)
class AnotherViewModel() {
    constructor(cvm) {
        this.externalRouter = cvm.router;
    }
    doStuff() {
        this.externalRouter.navigate('somewhere');
    }
    doOtherStuff() {
        ChildViewModel.router.navigate('somewhere else');
    }
}
```

Comment: Matt, your suggestion doesn't work.  Route is not found.

Comment: Thanks John. This code will not work line for line, because I made up fake routes like "somewhere" and "somewhere else". The error you're getting suggests that you're trying to navigate to a route that isn't defined in your router. If you need more help, get me on gitter, twitter, or email, and we'll take a look at your code.

Answer (score 0):

My friend helped me solve this. For the child router on first router navigation I had blank '' and it took the URL with like localhost:9000/. When I try to navigate from there I had problem. So from the first navigation, I changed to the code to route like childrouter/name and it worked.