# Aurelia - Dynamic redirect in a child route

Tags: aurelia

I have an Aurelia app, the parent and child router. Parent:

```
{ name: 'group', route: 'group/:groupId', viewPorts: {
    Filter: { moduleId: 'filter.js'},
    Content: { moduleId: 'content.js' }
}}
```

The child router is set up:

```
[
    { name: 'home',      route: ''          },
    { name: 'documents', route: 'documents' },
    { name: 'images',    route: 'images'    },
    { name: 'specs',     route: 'specs'     }
]
```

The child router is configured in `content.js`. I'd like to achieve, that in the parent router, I navigate without having specified the childs full path

```
router.navigateToRoute('group', { groupId: 12345 });
```

In the child router, this will end up in `home`, where I'd perform a dynamic redirect based on some app state. How should it be achieved? So far, I've tried these

With `RedirectToRoute`:

```
activate(params: any, config: any, instruction: NavigationInstruction): any {
    return new RedirectToRoute('pick one child route');
}
```

Inject `Router`:

```
@inject(Router)
export class Home {
    constructor(router: Router) {
        this.router = router;
    }
    activate(params: any, config: any, instruction: NavigationInstruction): void {
        this.router.navigateToRoute('pick one child route');
    }
}
```

The redirect/navigation itself is correct *locally*, however, the `baseUrl` of the (child) router still points to the old (parent) route, so the result will be incorrect.

*For example*: we are on a page of: `group/98765/images` and in the parent router, we navigate: `router.navigateToRoute('group', { groupId: 12345 });`. As expected, we'll end up `group/12345` and `home`'s `activate` method will be fired.

We redirect here, let's say to `specs`. But instead of `group/12345/specs`, we'll end up in `group/98765/specs`, due to outdated `baseUrl`.

How should it be fixed?

I've seen some related issues with child router's `baseUrl`, the suggestion was to *fix* manually to a constant, before navigating. However, due to templated routes (which are more complex, than shown in this example), this is not as easy as just setting the `baseUrl` to a constant string.

Comment: Maybe take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246901/aurelia-how-navigate-between-child-routes

Comment: I don't think your example is relevant, since you use static links, no dynamic redirect(s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although router events would work, but it is not elegant, since two navigation will occour and will appear in the browser history. If the user tries to navigate back, he/she cannot, because navigates back to `home` route, which'll immediately navigate forward to the selected child route.

The "right" way (in Aurelia documentation): use navigationStrategy callback when configuring the router. So this is how to set up the child router:

```
configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
    const navStrat = (instruction: NavigationInstruction) => {
        instruction.config.redirect = 'pick one child route';
    };
    config.map([
        { name: 'redirecter', route: '',         navigationStrategy: navStrat },
        { name: 'documents',  route: 'documents'                              },
        { name: 'images',     route: 'images'                                 },
        { name: 'specs',      route: 'specs'                                  }    
    ]);
}
```

This will result in one navigation cycle, and one can implement any dynamic redirect logic.

Comment: Mind, that `AppRouter` (the top-level router) sends `EventAggrerator` events, such as `'router:navigation:success'`. This is just not the best solution